# from __future__ import absolute_import not working? sub-modules not visible

Tags: python, import

So I've got a module `bbb` in the main scope as well as `ccc`.

I'm adding a library called `tools` which also has 2 modules called `bbb` and `ccc`:

> tools
>
> - `__init__.py`
> - aaa.py
> - bbb.py
> - ccc.py

In `bbb.py` I'm importing the main scope bbb with:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import bbb
```

and in `ccc.py` doing the same thing:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import ccc
```

but when I import tools and dir it I can only see:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__',
'__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'aaa']
```

but the `bbb` and `ccc` don't seem to be visible.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is there any special reason you're using the `__future__` stuff in this case?

Comment: `from __future__ import absolute_import` specifically turns off the implicit relative import behavior you're trying to use.

Comment: @Joe I think my particular case was not explained properly. there are modules ccc and bbb with the same names that live in the main scope. I have 2 modules under tools that have the same names and inside of each I'm importing the corresponding module from the main scope. That's why I thought I need to explicitly say that the imports are absolute.

Comment: It would be the opposite; you have to explicitely say that the imports are relative ;) And you must tell python relative to what ('.' is current module, '..' is parent module...). So you can have os (builtin), and tools.os (your stuff) and treat them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but when I import tools and dir it I can only see:
>
> ```
> ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__',
> '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'aaa']
> ```
>
> but the `bbb` and `ccc` don't seem to be visible.

Importing a package doesn't automatically load all its submodules. If you want to use the `tools.bbb` package, you need to do

```
import tools.bbb
# or
from tools import bbb
```

`import tools` won't cut it. Alternatively, you can have `tools` explicitly load its submodules in its `__init__.py`:

```
# in __init__.py
from . import aaa, bbb, ccc
```

Comment: That explains everything. Thanks!

Comment: Also if the tools are under another module topmodulename.tools what's the best approach to be using tools.bbb.calls() directly? How would you import this so you don't need to do long calls like topmodulename.tools.bbb.calls() IF you didn't want to import all the submodules in the tools.__init__ ?

Comment: @mtmt: `from topmodulename.tools import bbb`

Answer (score 1):

Use the dot notation:

From `bbb.py`, if you want to import `aaa.py`:

```
from . import aaa
```

From outside tools, if you want to import `tools/aaa.py`:

```
from tools import aaa
```

Comment: thanks. Can I still do import tools and call tools.bbb.somemethod() ?

Comment: hmmm - that's not exactly what I was after. I need to import bbb from inside of bbb.py (bbb module is in the main scope) that's why I'm using the absolute_import but still having trouble seeing the bbb.py and ccc.py modules when do import tools; tools.bbb ("tools has no module called bbb")